# positioning elements inside a containing div?

Tags: css

i´ve got elements inside a containing div with a class.

i could use text-align: center on the div and that will center all elements.

how could i position the elements with exact pixels from the left?

(i dont want to use css on the element but on the containing div)

Comment: Why don't you want to style the children?

Comment: just want everything the div to be positioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `padding-left` on the container div. However this will augment the width of the div itself, since you're adding left padding to it. To solve this problem you should use `margin-left` on the inner divs, for example:

```
/* apply a margin left to all the divs
 * inside div.container
 */
div.container div {
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The closest you could get with only the div is to play with the `padding`, but the correct solution would be to apply left/top to the inner elements.

Also, this belongs on doctype.com.

Comment: Doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).

Answer (score 2):

Set position: relative
Set top: ..px
Set left: ..px

I think this solution is prettier than setting margins/paddings.

(I'm typing this on an iPhone can't format it for ya)

Comment: The question was asking for how to do it without touching the inner elements, hence the padding hack.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is what your looking for 
     < div style="position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;top:100px;left:100px;">
You can put that style on any tag you want Enjoy!
and to be into the middle use I.E
     <  div style="position:absolute;top:0px;***left:50%;***">